# npyscreen - get NPSAppManaged screen width?

Tags: npyscreen

I try to center a widget and so getting the screen width from the form

```
class myForm(npyscreen.Form):
   def create(self):
      # Center the form horizontally
      self.show_atx = 0
      center = self.width / 2
      center = self.parentApp.COLS /2
      ...
```

I also tried to use onResize() but it has no w/h parameters to rely on

how can I get the screen size ?

thanks for your help
but there is nothing like width or similar in that class

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR:

1. You're not supposed to
2. ScreenSize.py and TESTING-TinyForm.py in the github repo
3. Use Textual instead

### (1) Widget Positioning

The widget positioning system is based on a relative x,y coordinate system. The layout engine tries to place widgets in the left-most columns by default - see `add_widget` and `create_widgets_from_list`.

### (2) Layout

`ScreenSize.py` gives us `self.F = npyscreen.Form(name = "Welcome to Npyscreen")` and `self.F._max_physical()`

`npyscreen`doesn't have a `Form` class. Checking `__init__.py`, this has a relative import: `from .fmForm import Form`, which has a relative import to `proto_fm_screen_area`. This has a `ScreenArea` class providing three useful functions:

`_max_physical(self)` -> raw size test
`useable_space(self, rely=0, relx=0)` -> safer size check
`widget_useable_space(self, rely=0, relx=0)` -> probably should use this

The return from these provides (rows, columns). Potentially these can be used to calculate the positioning for a centre widget.

Going back to `fmForm.py` and `class _FormBase(proto_fm_screen_area.ScreenArea`, the function `add_widget(rely=None, relx=None)` can be called where rely is the centre column to place the widget.

If F is the form, my_widget is widget, and the 3rd column is the centre, `self.add_widget(widgetClass = my_widget, relx=3)` should put the widget at the centre-top of the form.

`TESTING-TinyForm.py` demonstrates a method to create a fixed size screen `TinyForm(lines=1, columns=0)` which might be easier if planning to force a centre widget. Using a pre-planned number of lines and columns would avoid the need to calculate the position. If I understand the code correctly, when the form is too big for the terminal then managed apps will automatically supply a scrollbar.

### (3) Textual

`npyscreen` was (is?) a nice curses library. It's very old now and really could use a big cleanup.

[Textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual) is a modern codebase from Will Mcgugan, who is also the author of [Rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich).

This can use [CSS layouts, or direct widget layouts](https://textual.textualize.io/guide/layout/), including a [Grid-style layout](https://textual.textualize.io/api/containers/#textual.containers.Grid).

An example of what you want can be inferred from the ["5x5" code example](https://github.com/Textualize/textual/blob/main/examples/five_by_five.py):

```
class GameCell(Button):
    def __init__(self, row: int, col: int) -> None:
```

With a fixed "5x5" grid to place the widgets on, it is trivial to place a centre widget.

Comment: is Textual linux/win compatible ?

Comment: [Textual apps run on MacOS, Linux, and Windows. In the terminal, the web, and Jupyter notebooks.](https://www.textualize.io/)